# MySQL count number of matching rows always returns 1

Tags: php, mysql

I've checked the SQL below in mySQL and it returns the correct count of products that the user has. I'm trying to move the statement into a PHP to execute conditional code based on the product count. However, the echo always returns 1. What am I missing?

```
$sql = "select count(product_id) from dap_users_products_jn where product_id not in(13,34) and user_id = 1";
$stmt = $dap_dbh->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt = $stmt->rowCount();
echo "the product count is: ".$stmt;
```

Comment: `rowCount()` is not for `SELECT` statements.  See the docs: http://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php

Comment: You only get one row containing the count of product_ids.

Comment: Yes, you have _1_ row, with _1_ field, which you need to _fetch_ to see what the _value_ of it is ;)

Comment: See it as `count(array(123))` => that would be.. _1_, not _123_.

Comment: Just return the result, the sql has taken care of the count.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will always get one row returned when using `COUNT()` this way as you have to get a result set even if the result of `COUNT()` is zero. Or else how will you know what the results are? If you want the results of `COUNT()` you need to get the results of your query as normal and then check the value of the `COUNT()` operation.

```
$sql = "select count(product_id) AS prod_count from dap_users_products_jn where product_id not in(13,34) and user_id = 1";
$stmt = $dap_dbh->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
echo "the product count is: ".$result->prod_count;
```

Answer (score 1):

What you should do is, get the column. **PDO** have the **fetchColumn** function which gets the columns. You should use it instead of `$stmt->rowCount()`

```
$sql = "select count(product_id) from dap_users_products_jn where product_id not in(13,34) and user_id = 1";
$stmt = $dap_dbh->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt = $stmt->fetchColumn();
echo "the product count is: ".$stmt;
```

Since **SQL** already fetched the row count why use PDO's rowCount() ?